# How to split column then compare the split list with another list?

Tags: sqlite

I need to SELECT a value from a table, convert it into a list, then search through that list if it is in another list, only one have to match.

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
_id    name    group

1      Bob     mathematics,science,information technology...(list can be any size)
2      John    science,mathematics,natural science,life orientation...(list can be any size)
```

and I have the following array:

```
arr = [science,mathematics]
```

I need to split the group column via the comma delimiter.

```
 ["mathematics","science","information technology"]
```

Then compare this list with my `arr` array. And if 1 of them matches, return all the fields.

I have tried `substr` and `instr` but couldn't get it to work.

```
SELECT substr(groups, 1, pos-1) AS g FROM (SELECT groups, instr(groups, ',') AS pos FROM courses WHERE _id = 2);
```

but this only returns the first one. not sure if this is possible in sqlite3, with no added libraries.

This is what needs to happen:

```
SELECT * FROM subject WHERE ["mathematics","science","information technology"] in ("science","mathematics")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using [WITH RECURSIVE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html). The thought being: create a virtual view that tokenizes the "group" column. It is based on your substr/instr approach, by putting each group element in one row of the view. Here is a sample query:

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
>   glist(id, head, rest) AS (
>  
> select id,
> CASE when instr(groups,",") = 0 then groups else substr(groups,1,instr(groups,',')-1) END, -- head
> CASE when instr(groups,',') = 0 then groups else substr(groups,instr(groups,',') + 1) END --rest
>
> from subjects 
>
>
> UNION ALL
> SELECT id, substr(rest,1,instr(rest,',') - 1), --head
> substr(rest,instr(rest,',')+1) -- rest
>
>  FROM glist
>  WHERE id = id
>  and  instr(rest,',') !=0 -- base case
> )
> select distinct subjects.*
> from glist g
> JOIN subjects on subjects.id = g.id
> where head in ('science','mathematics')
> order by id
> ```

NB to "see" what `glist` looks like, replace the `select distinct....` query with `select * from glist`

Comment: That is genius! Works amazing!